# when mysql will assign a transaction id to a transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb

I want to know when mysql will assign a transaction id to a transaction。
when I start a transaction by enter begin in command line,will the mysql assign a transaction id to this transaction?If not,when the transaction id will be assign?

Comment: Why does this matter? There is no reliable way for querying transaction ids in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

No, in fact the transaction id doesn't appear until you issue your first SQL statement after you begin a transaction.

You can demonstrate this.

Begin a transaction:

```
mysql> select connection_id();
+-----------------+
| connection_id() |
+-----------------+
|              74 |
+-----------------+
mysql> begin;
```

But notice that the transaction id for your current connection is still listed as 0:

```
mysql> show engine innodb status\G
...
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 74, OS thread handle 0x7000025a1000, query id 1436 localhost root init
show engine innodb status
```

Then once you do a query, InnoDB suddenly realizes that it needs to create a transaction to start a snapshot.

```
mysql> select * from test.mytable;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

And now the transaction id appears, associated with the current session:

```
mysql> show engine innodb status\G
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 5669850, ACTIVE 3 sec
MySQL thread id 74, OS thread handle 0x7000025a1000, query id 1441 localhost root init
show engine innodb status
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.My Mysql version is 5.7.27,but when I run select snapshot sql,the transaction not active,but when I run update sql or insert sql,the transaction active.And when I try Mysql 5.6,the result was same to yours.Is this change from mysql5.7?